# Cycles not rendering VDB Cloud while using Google Colab for rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So I started using Google Colab a few days ago and it was all good until I encountered a serious issue. Not sure if it's a Colab issue or Blender, but when I render a scene containing VDB Clouds, the clouds just disappear. But if I use my own machine for rendering, the clouds are rendered so I think it's an issue from Colab's side probably.
Any fix/workaround for this? Maybe those clouds need to be baked?
[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RSh0oQfDuf_vDliZ1h01Fcsvenye31jE/view?usp=sharing) the .blend File with all the textures and meshes inside of it.[image: And here's the render of the project]

Comment: Hi and welcome :) would need information about your scene to be abale to really answer your question. Please [add more information](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/198508/edit) (*images*, a [*blend file*](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) with [*all textures packed*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html#pack-all)), ect, so that other users can more easily understand your question. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey I did the required editing can you please look into this now? Thanks!

Comment: I am also using Google colab, so I think it is maybe because you didn't pack all the files in .blend file

Comment: You could always bake them, though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Blender does not pack VDB files cuz they are pretty heavy.
and if you could upload the VDBs to colab and tell somehow that these are the missing files you have to render than it will surely render those clouds.
if there are vdbs present than blender automatically replaces them with the scenes
Hopefully someone come with a code for